# How to load website layout(header,footer) using js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am newbie in javascript. I want to load my website main template file(header,footer,sidebar) using ajax. My layout file is given below.

layout.php

```
<?php
   $app = new App;
   $ret = $app->header();
   $ret .= $app->sidebar();
   $ret .= $app->footer();
   echo json_encode($ret);
?>
```

Now I want to load my layout file using ajax. As there is no div initially. How can I load this.My js file is given below.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'layout.php',
  dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(resp){
  //here is problem
  //as initially no div is present
  //how can I load it with jquery
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, looks fine. Don't forget the asynchronous of queries. So your code will:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'layout.php',
  dataType: 'json',
}).done(function(resp){
  $('#content').html(resp.layout);
});

<?php
   $app = new App;
   $ret = $app->header();
   $ret .= $app->sidebar();
   $ret .= $app->footer();
   echo json_encode({layout: $ret});
 ?>
```

Comment: $('#content') div is not present. Initially with blank pages.

Comment: use then $('body'), or create it